# Dynamic Table in JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick

This is my code snippet...

```
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {   
        s=xmlhttp.responseText;
        info=s.split("!");
        elem=document.getElementById("add_players1");
        for (var i = 0 ;i < (info.length-1);i++ ) 
        {
        var row=elem.insertRow(-1); //here is where I need to call a function when I click on the element
        var x=row.insertCell(-1);
        var y=row.insertCell(-1);
        var z=row.insertCell(-1);
        temp=info[i].split(",");
        name=temp[0];
        val=temp[1];
        pos=temp[2];
        x.innerHTML=name;
        y.innerHTML=val;
        z.innerHTML=pos;

    }
```

Basically what I have done is received some data from my PHP file and dynamically created a table but what I want is that when I click on an individual element of the table a function to run. I am stuck here as I have dynamically created a table hence don't know how to make the function call ... Kindly advice

Comment: Also something i felt might help .. Is it possible to create a element such div,p,a etc with Ids in the fashion that i have used above ?

Comment: You forget some var keyword inclusions. var s = xmlhttp.responseText etc. So you will not create globals by accident. I also must say that using jQuery makes ajax calls a lot easier. Or what about this $.post('foo.php', {formvar: "value"}, function(webpage) { var info = webpage.split("!"; /* etc */ });

Comment: When using jQuery, you create elements easily (to actually connect more with your question). var div = $('<div id="foo"/>'); otherdiv.append(div);

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the event to the element in javascript by using onclick property
on the element ,

```
var myfunction = function()
{
    alert("row clicked, id "+ this.id+", text"+this.innerHTML);
}

function addRow(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {   
        s=xmlhttp.responseText;
        info=s.split("!");
        elem=document.getElementById("add_players1");
        for (var i = 0 ;i < (info.length-1);i++ ) 
        {
        var row=elem.insertRow(-1); 
        row.onclick = myfunction;
        temp=info[i].split(",");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; i++) {
               appendDiv(row.insertCell(j), temp[j] , 'divStyle');
        }
    }
}

function appendDiv(cell, text, style) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'), 
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); 
    div.appendChild(txt);                    
    div.setAttribute('className', style);    
    cell.appendChild(div);                   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Avinash I shall try the new code and get back with any doubts. :)

Comment: @prahaladp Updated the answer with example of appending a Div